# Replace values row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am having a dataframe with the following columns:

```
  Index(['fullName', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'companyUrl', 'Domain',
   'Email Format 1', 'Email Format 2', 'Email Format 3'],
  dtype='object')
```

The data is like this

```
   fullName     firstName   lastName    companyName    Domain        Email Format 1          Email Format 2          Email Format 3
0   Olamide A.  Olamide         A       Wells Fargo  wellsfargo.com jane.doe@wellsfargo.com   jane@wellsfargo.com   jdoe@wellsfargo.com
```

Sample Data: [Dataframe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADR2D.jpg)

Now I want to perform with jane.doe is there then replace with firstname.lastname , if jane is there replace with firstname and if jdoe is there replace with first letter of firstname + lastname

Can anybody please help we with coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide some better sample. Here is what I managed to quickly put together.

```
>>> my_index = pd.Index(['fullName', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'companyUrl', 'Domain',
    ...:    'Email Format 1', 'Email Format 2', 'Email Format 3'],
    ...:   dtype='object')

# Adding some sample data to dict `d`
>>> d={0: {'fullName': 'Olamide',
    ...:   'firstName': 'A.',
    ...:   'lastName': 'Olamide',
    ...:   'companyUrl': 'A',
    ...:   'Domain': 'wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 1': 'jane.doe@wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 2': 'jane@wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 3': 'jdoe@wellsfargo.com'}
    ...: ,
    ...: 1: {'fullName': 'Plamide',
    ...:   'firstName': 'D.',
    ...:   'lastName': 'Plamide',
    ...:   'companyUrl': 'D',
    ...:   'Domain': 'wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 1': 'jadoe@wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 2': 'jane@wellsfargo.com',
    ...:   'Email Format 3': 'jdoe@wellsfargo.com'}
    ...:   }

# Converting dict `d` to dataframe
>>> df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

# Checking original entries
>>> df
  fullName firstName lastName companyUrl          Domain           Email Format 1       Email Format 2       Email Format 3
0  Olamide        A.  Olamide          A  wellsfargo.com  jane.doe@wellsfargo.com  jane@wellsfargo.com  jdoe@wellsfargo.com
1  Plamide        D.  Plamide          D  wellsfargo.com     jadoe@wellsfargo.com  jane@wellsfargo.com  jdoe@wellsfargo.com

# Define function to replace any 'jane.doe' findings
>>> def f(row):
    replaced = []
    for cell in row:
        if 'jane.doe' in str(cell):
             cell = re.sub('jane.doe', ''.join([row.firstName, row.lastName]), cell)

        replaced.append(cell)

    return pd.Series(replaced, index=my_index)


>>> df.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[94]:
  fullName firstName lastName companyUrl          Domain            Email Format 1       Email Format 2       Email Format 3
0  Olamide        A.  Olamide          A  wellsfargo.com  A.Olamide@wellsfargo.com  jane@wellsfargo.com  jdoe@wellsfargo.com
1  Plamide        D.  Plamide          D  wellsfargo.com      jadoe@wellsfargo.com  jane@wellsfargo.com  jdoe@wellsfargo.com
```

Not terrible, not great ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestion. I have changed the sample structure. Can you please help me out with the code

Comment: Getting Error TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Please provide sample data. Also, avoid changing requirements over time as what you did now kinda invalidates my response/answer :-)

Comment: Hey, I have provided an image of the dataframe I am having right now. Will this work ?

Comment: Providing images is typically a very bad practice and must be avoided. I have updated the answer now. The problem is that you have null values so I just wrapped that in str(). Just copy the `f()` function again & it should work

Comment: If I use using str(cell) it gives error 'str' object is not callable